# Matlab initialize 3D array with a 2D array

Tags: arrays, matlab

Is there a simple way to create a 3D array in which each layer is initialized with a given 2D array? I could use the following `for` loop, but it's very slow.

```
a = rand(1000);
b = zeros(1000, 1000, 1000);
for i = 1:1000
  b(:,:,i) = a;
end
```

Comment: try [repmat](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html)

Comment: Thank you! `repmat(a,1,1,1000)` solves the problem!

Comment: If the goal is actually to initialize your array with random values, you can call `rand(1000,1000,1000)`

Comment: @user728826 Just curious, how much faster was `repmat`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `repmat` or `repelem` equivalently here

```
a = rand(10,10);

b = repmat( a, 1, 1, 1000 );
c = repelem( a, 1, 1, 1000 );
```

You can also use implicit expansion, although it's not as clear to read

```
d = a + zeros( 1, 1, 1000 );
```